# Удаление подстроки - пути на ФС

Tags: php

Всем доброго дня. Имеется строка, содержащая такое:

> `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/ostream:581:69:
> note: template<class _CharT, class
> _Traits, class _Tp> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
> std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
> _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/ostream:528:77:
> note: template<class _Traits>
> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&
> std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char,
> _Traits>&, const unsigned char*) /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/ostream:523:75:
> note: template<class _Traits>`

Каким образом можно удалить весь путь к файлу, оставив лишь его имя? Спасибо.

Comment: Не увидел здесь массива.

Comment: упс) это в строке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор замены (в perl, в php д.б. так же, в sed надо корректировать): `s/^([^:]+)\///`
. Удаляет с начала строки все не :, заканчивающиеся /